# Number of Leaf Nodes in a Binary Tree at a given Level?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

Given a Binary Tree, how can we find the number of Leaf nodes at a particular level, considering the level of the root is 1 and so on.

Comment: If you assume it's filled, then it's 2^n where n=0 is the root. If you assume each level contains the minimal number of nodes then it's 1 for every level. Else, it could be anything in between, and you'll have to do a traversal to find out

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I got it Clarified!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use BFS or DFS algorithm. Something like that (in pseudocode):

Node_counter(root, N):

   1. IF root is null or N<1 return 0

   2. IF N==1 

        2.1 if root is leaf return 1

        2.2 otherwise return 0

   3. Otherwise return Node_counter(root->left, N-1)+Node_counter(root->right, N-1)

Complexity is O(N)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private int noOfleafLevel(Node root, int leaflevel) {
        if(root==null)
            return 0;
        if(root.left==null&&root.right==null&&leaflevel==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return noOfleafLevel(root.left, leaflevel - 1)+noOfleafLevel(root.right, leaflevel - 1);
    }
```

This is the code for getting Leaf at a particular level, using level order traversal.